# swift 3 - UIRefreshControl not working in large screen

Tags: ios, swift3, screen, uirefreshcontrol

I have a `UICollectionView` in which I want to integrate a `UIRefreshControl` in order to enable user to swipe down to refresh.

Say I have 5 items in my `UICollectionView`. If I run my app in an iPhone5, then `UIRefreshControl` works beautifully. However, if I run it in an iPhone6Plus (where all 5 items are fit in screen), the `UIRefreshControl` just does not work any more; I even cannot swipe it down.

Is there any properties in `UIRefreshControl` that can help user to swipe down in any situations, no matter what size the screen is? I took a look at `UIRefreshControl` class below but it seems these cannot help:

```
public init()


open var isRefreshing: Bool { get }


open var tintColor: UIColor!

open var attributedTitle: NSAttributedString?


// May be used to indicate to the refreshControl that an external event has initiated the refresh action
@available(iOS 6.0, *)
open func beginRefreshing()

// Must be explicitly called when the refreshing has completed
@available(iOS 6.0, *)
open func endRefreshing()
```

An ugly solution is to make a refresh button, which I don't want.

You have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because your collectionView's `contentSize` isn't large enough to scroll. (It's smaller than your screen size).

UIRefreshControl only works when your scrollView is scrollable.

If you would like to make your `UICollectionView` always scrollable.

Set the `alwaysBounceVertical` property to `true`. (Which is inherited by `UIScrollView`)